# Difficulties with dynamically identifying enum member

Tags: c#, xna

```
    public enum Levels
    {
        LevelState1 = 0,
        LevelState2 = 1,
        LevelState3 = 2
    }
    private Levels currentLevel;
    public void ChooseLevel(Levels levelstate)
    {
        switch (levelstate)
        {
            case Levels.LevelState1:
                currentLevel = Levels.LevelState1;
        ...
                break;
            case Levels.LevelState2:
                currentLevel = Levels.LevelState2;
        ...     
                break;
            case Levels.LevelState3:
                currentLevel = Levels.LevelState3;
        ...
                break;
        }
    }

//The variable CurrentLevel is an integer
ChooseLevel(Levels."LevelState"+game1.CurrentLevel.ToString());
```

I always get this error message in the last line:
Identifier expected 
What should I change? I don't know how to fix this problem.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do there? It doesn't make much sense..!

Comment: Or you could just use an integer instead of the enumeration.

Comment: Besides the wrong syntax this sounds like you're having a design problem making the whole thing a lot more complicated than necessary: Why the back/forth with the enum, then passing it as a string? Is there anything keeping you from just using an integer (or the enum) for identification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel that you are overcomplicating things. You can do this much simpler in a way similar to this:

```
    public enum Levels
{
    LevelState1 = 1,
    LevelState2 = 2,
    LevelState3 = 3
}
private Levels currentLevel;
public void ChooseLevel(int state)
{
    currentLevel = (Levels)state; // casting to enum from int
    // process level or whatever here
}

//The variable CurrentLevel is an integer
ChooseLevel(game1.CurrentLevel);
```

Since your CurrentLevel variable is an integer, you can easily cast it to your enum by binding level states to actual integer values within the level range. So instead of starting at 0 in your enum, you start at the first level value (which in your case is 1, no?).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Either wrap this in a `try/catch`:

```
Levels level = (Levels)Enum.Parse(typeof(Levels), 
                                       "LevelState" + game1.CurrentLevel.ToString());
ChooseLevel(level);
```

Or use [`Enum.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`ChooseLevel` expectes `enum` argument, whereas you're using a mixture of enum and string, you'll have to parse it:

```
Levels game1Level = (Levels)Enum.Parse(typeof(Levels), "LevelState" + game1.CurrentLevel);
ChooseLevel(game1Level);
```

You can also use [`Enum.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)